# Android LocationManager GPS_PROVIDER time is different from NETWORK_PROVIDER time

Tags: android, networking, time, gps, location

I have an issue that I cant figure out why is happening.

On my Location Listener class I have initialized location updates for all available providers:

```
List<String> providers = locationManager.getProviders(true);
for (String provider : providers) {
     locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(provider, locationUpdatesInterval, discardLocations, this);
}
```

When I start get locations, I receive locations from gps/network/passive providers, so that is working correct. But the problem is that when I want to draw the route I figure out that the location.getTime() is getting different time depending on the provider, but the location is good according to my needs (high accuracy, smallestDisplacement, etc).

Is there any reason why location.getTime() values are different (between GPS and NETWORK specifically)? Both are being showing with the same format:

```
Date date = new Date(time);
```

A print of my DB locations collected looks like this (yellow marked locations are from network provider and its time is older than the others -GPS_Locations- by a few minutes):

https://i.stack.imgur.com/9DTd4.png

TIME Column is the location.getTime() value (are consecutive when is same provider).

SEND_DATE column is my current date when executed (are consecutive).

Comment: `getting different hours `. Different hours? It looks more like a little difference in seconds.

Comment: yes, It is diffferent, according to my SEND_DATE must be consecutive, but  when I get a location from network provider, I get a time different from my gps time.

Comment: You are not coming to the point of my remark. You suggest that the difference is hours. But it is only seconds. You should have told that in your post to begin with.  And tell in your post who has the rigth time. Did you investigate?

Comment: @greenapps thanks for your quicly reply. The differences are obviously just a few minutes. but when you try to follow a route with the locations, these are not organized because of GPS TIME is different from NETWORK TIME. The rigth time for me is the send_date but obviosuly if I sort locations by my send_date, i wont have a fluent route.

Comment: Before we deep into solving your problem you have to find out who delivers the right time. The gps or the network. I asked that before. Compare the time with your clock. With your neighbours click. With the TV clock. But first find out!

Comment: My send_date column is taken from phone and phone is sync with network. I consider GPS time as the right because I have preference when i get GPS locations (network locations I just use them when there is not sky sight). If I compare with my tv clock or computer clock, both are wrong: GPS is 2 minutes above and NETWORK is 3 minutes below.

Comment: If you just only would use send_date_time then you were done. Why aren't you doing so?

Comment: I need to use location time because send_date is phone time, If user changes to manually time, then I would get an incorrect hour. send_date is just for debugging.